# Linq to Entities - Get First Image from products in categorie

Tags: linq-to-entities

i'm having some trouble in making this on right.
I'm trying to get the first image from each product inside a specific categorie, but so far i get all fotos, repeating the product list:

```
 Dim Produtos = (From P In ProductsCtx.produto _
                 Join C In ProductsCtx.categoria On C.id Equals P.categoria_1.id _
                 Group Join F In ProductsCtx.FotosSet On F.produto.id Equals P.id Into Fotos = Group _
                 From Foto In Fotos.Take(1) _
                 Where C.id = Categorie _
                 Select New With {
                   .idProduto = P.id, 
                   .Foto = Foto.idFoto, 
                   .NomeProduto = P.nome, 
                   .Preco = P.precoActual}).ToList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i got this one:

```
Dim Produtos = (From P In ProductsCtx.produto _
                Join C In ProductsCtx.categoria On C.id Equals P.categoria_1.id _
                Where C.id = Categorie _
                Select New With {
                    .idProduto = P.id, 
                    .Foto = (From Ft In ProductsCtx.FotosSet 
                             Where P.id = Ft.produto.id 
                             Select Ft.idFoto).FirstOrDefault, 
                    .NomeProduto = P.nome, 
                    .Preco = P.precoActual}).ToList
```

Works for me =)